# What is the best place to ask about math algorithms in games?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about finding of the best algorithm to win in a turn-based logic game. What is the best Stack Exchange community to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828832/hex-game-winning-strategy) are on-topic on [Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com). They have a tag [combinatorial game theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-game-theory):

> Combinatorial game theory (abbreviated CGT) is the subfield of combinatorics (not traditional game theory) which deals with games of perfect information such as Nim and Go.

You can check the [top-voted questions for this tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-game-theory?sort=votes&pageSize=15) to get an idea of what information should be included in your question to make it well received by the community.